# C++ Some variables "used uninitialized in this function". Why?

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void input_function(int hour, int minutes);
void calcuation(int hour, int minutes, char meridien);
void output_function(int hour, int minutes, char meridien);

int main ()
{
  int hour, minutes;
  char answer, meridien;

  do
    {
      input_function(hour, minutes);
      calcuation(hour, minutes, meridien);
      output_function(hour, minutes, meridien);


      cout << "Would you like to try again? (Y/N)\n";
      cin >> answer;

    } while(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');

  cout <<"Goodbye\n";

  return 0;
}

void input_function(int hour, int minutes)
{
  cout << "Enter the hour in 24 hour notation: (Ex. 23)\n";
  cin >> hour;

  cout << "Enter the minutes:\n";
  cin >> minutes;
}

void calcuation(int hour, int minutes, char meridien)
{
  if (hour > 12)
    {
      hour = hour - 12;
      meridien = 'P';
    }
  else 
    {
      meridien = 'A';
    }
}

void output_function(int hour, int minutes, char meridien)
{
  cout << "Your time in 12 hour notation is:\n";
  cout << hour << ":" << minutes << endl;

  if (meridien == 'P')
    cout << "P.M.\n";

  else 
    cout << "A.M\n";
}
```

The compiler is giving me the following errors:

Problem2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

Problem2.cpp:15:36: warning: ‘hour’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
       input_function(hour, minutes);

Problem2.cpp:15:36: warning: ‘minutes’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Problem2.cpp:16:41: warning: ‘meridien’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       calcuation(hour, minutes, meridien);

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on how to pass parameters by value vs. by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Your input_function should pass by reference.

If you pass by value only, it would not affect anything.

```
  #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    void input_function(int& hour, int& minutes);
    void calcuation(int hour, int minutes, char meridien);
    void output_function(int hour, int minutes, char meridien);

    int main ()
    {
      int hour, minutes;
      char answer, meridien;

      do
        {
          input_function(hour, minutes);
          calcuation(hour, minutes, meridien);
          output_function(hour, minutes, meridien);


          cout << "Would you like to try again? (Y/N)\n";
          cin >> answer;

        } while(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');

      cout <<"Goodbye\n";

      return 0;
    }

    void input_function(int& hour, int& minutes)
    {
      cout << "Enter the hour in 24 hour notation: (Ex. 23)\n";
      cin >> hour;

      cout << "Enter the minutes:\n";
      cin >> minutes;
    }

    void calcuation(int hour, int minutes, char meridien)
    {
      if (hour > 12)
        {
          hour = hour - 12;
          meridien = 'P';
        }
      else 
        {
          meridien = 'A';
        }
    }

    void output_function(int hour, int minutes, char meridien)
    {
      cout << "Your time in 12 hour notation is:\n";
      cout << hour << ":" << minutes << endl;

      if (meridien == 'P')
        cout << "P.M.\n";

      else 
        cout << "A.M\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting about uninitialized variables means that the program is trying to use the variables without them being assigned a value. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable) defines them as follows:

> In computing, an uninitialized variable is a variable that is declared but is not set to a definite known value before it is used. It will have some value, but not a predictable one. As such, it is a programming error and a common source of bugs in software.

**To fix these errors** you might try to give your variables initial values. The actual number used shouldn't matter unless its to big for the integer.

Its also very likely that when you fix that, that your program will not do what you expect. That is because currently your functions are accepting parameters, but not actually changing the variables in your `int main()` function.

There are a couple of ways to fix this. You could pass by reference:

```
void input_function(int& hour, int& minutes)
{
  //things happen, the & sign before the variables is the important part
}
```

Doing this would let the function interact with the variables that you actually want to use, and is probably the best way to tackle this.

Or if that's confusing might also try declaring them as [global variables](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/) or making your functions return integer values.

Best of luck!